# Read data from PostgreSQL in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have some problem.
need to connect to the PostgreSQL DB, read the id and write the maximum to the last_client variable. But the call occurs asynchronously and the result is not recorded. How to write the result to a variable?

```
let Databases = require('pg');
let db = new Databases.Client("postgres://postgres:****@localhost:5432/****");
db.connect();
let last_client = -1;
db.query("SELECT id_pacients FROM clients", (err, res) => {
    for (let row of res.rows){
        id = Math.max(row.id_pacients, id)
    }
});
```

Comment: May be "SELECT id AS id_pacients FROM clients". Or easier, "SELECT max(id) FROM clients"

Comment: You do not need to iterate a recordset on all table. Use PostgreSQL math functions instead. "SELECT max(id_pacients) AS max_pacients FROM clients", you'll get a single value, then store it into last_client, I guess.